# How to fix P4PASSWD is invalid or unset in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, perforce

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0). I installed Perforce Plugin -  P4Eclipse 2018.5. Whenever I add a new Perforce connection, I get an error "Perforce Password (P4PASSWRD) invalid or unset"

I have tried the following:
1. Adding P4PASSWD in the registry
2. Adding P4PASSWD in the env variables

I should be able to connect to Perforce through Eclipse. My Perforce client connects just fine using the same server connection settings.

Comment: Try logging in first before you fire up Eclipse (p4 login).

Comment: My p4 client is always connected. Is there another way of p4 login through eclipse?

Comment: I always find Eclipse a little wiggy.  Sometimes feels like I have to turn around three times and do a little dance to get Eclipse to do what I want... The thing about  using p4login, it should keep your session alive without having to explicitly enter the password as an env variable.